# How to convert a set of button controlled bootstrap 2 tab pages to bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, upgrade

I am converting my bootstrap 2 site to bootstrap 3 and am a bit stuck on a particular control which is several sets of tab pages controlled by toggle buttons.

Here is an example of my working bs2 code:

http://bootply.com/97187

If I run this code in bs3, I get this:

http://bootply.com/97189

The problem as you will see is that the buttons no longer behave like a group of radio buttons. They toggle individually.

I am currently here:

http://bootply.com/97184

This looks like it works but it doesn't. The grey colour you get when you click on a button is in fact, the "I've now got the focus" colour. Click somewhere else and it goes back to white.

I **really** need the buttons to toggle as they did in bs2. What small thing am I neglecting here?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in here:

```
<div class="well well-sm"> 
  <span>Set A:</span>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default active" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">2</button>
  </div>
  <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Set B:</span>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="#tabA" data-toggle="tab">A</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="#tabB" data-toggle="tab">B</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="#tabC" data-toggle="tab">C</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Adding the class `active` to the button  class for `tab1` seemed to prevent the buttons from toggling as you want them to. Simply removing the `active` class seems to fix the problem.

Demo: http://bootply.com/97199

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however the highlighting you see here is simply the "got focus" colour. As soon as you click anywhere else, it will disappear. I need it to persist, as per the "active" class.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've been playing around quite a bit and got to an acceptable solution.

Unlike the Bootstrap 2 version, it requires a bit of JavaScript.

Here it is: http://bootply.com/97426

The only thing it doesn't do is group the button groups into a single component but this is acceptable, unless someone can find a way to do this as well.

Would be nicer if Bootstrap just worked the same way as V2 in this case.